# 'Simple' sql query. Rewrite it without using a subquery

Tags: sql

I am supposed to rewrite a SQL-query without using a subquery.
My solution which uses a subquery is:

```sql
SELECT * from parts WHERE weight > 
(SELECT weight from parts WHERE name = 'tape-drive');
```

A simplified version of my table 'parts':

```
NAME    WEIGHT  
----------------------  
line-printer    520     
tape-drive      100    
line-printer      520  
tape-drive        100         
byte-soap          75          
card-punch        120
```

I've thought about it for quite some time and am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering, because it's not often that I can;

```
SELECT P1.* 
  from parts P1
  join parts P2 on
       P1.weight > P2.weight
 WHERE P2.name = 'tape drive'
```

Comment: It sure works. But the stuff I was reading seem to be useless in this case. Must be reading the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but I'll give you a push.  You want to use a self INNER JOIN on the parts table.